# Быстрое чтение большого файла и конвертация ebcdic to ancii

Tags: java, файлы

Имеется файл огромных размеров формата ebcdic. Нужно конвертировать его в ANCII. Файл весит от 250Мб. Если все считать, конвертировать, разделить на массив строк, то это занимает много времени, и самое главное, много памяти на это уходит (ооочень много). Нужно реализовать механизм быстрого чтения и конвертации, чтобы еще памяти меньше ушло на это.

Старый алгоритм, который не рекомендую использовать.

```
      private static final char[] NON_PRINTABLE_EBCDIC_CHARS = new char[] { /*0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06,
            0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24 *//*, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06,
            0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19,
            0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F, 0x20, 0x7F, 0x80, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x85, 0x86, 0x87, 0x88, 0x89,
            0x8A, 0x8B, 0x8C, 0x8D, 0x8E, 0x8F, 0x90, 0x91, 0x92, 0x93, 0x94, 0x95, 0x96, 0x97, 0x98, 0x99, 0x9A, 0x9B,
            0x9C, 0x9D, 0x9E, 0xA0*/ };


 public String convert(String input) throws IOException {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        Reader reader = null;

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(input)), ebcdicCharset));
        int[] ebcdicInput = loadContent(reader);
        close(reader);
        convert(ebcdicInput, writer);
        return writer.toString();

    }

     private int[] loadContent(Reader reader) throws IOException {
        int[] buffer = new int[INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bufferIndex = 0;
        int bufferSize = buffer.length;
        int character;
        while ((character = reader.read()) != -1) {
            if (bufferIndex == bufferSize) {
                buffer = resizeArray(buffer, bufferSize + INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE);
                bufferSize = buffer.length;
            }
            buffer[bufferIndex++] = character;
        }
        return resizeArray(buffer, bufferIndex);
    }
     final int[] resizeArray(int[] orignalArray, int newSize) {
        int[] resizedArray = new int[newSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < newSize && i < orignalArray.length; i++) {
            resizedArray[i] = orignalArray[i];
        }
        return resizedArray;
    }

     private void convert(int[] ebcdicInput, Writer convertedOutputWriter) throws IOException {
        int convertedChar;
        for (int index = 0; index < ebcdicInput.length; index++) {
            int character = ebcdicInput[index];
            if (fixedLength != -1 && index > 0 && index % fixedLength == 0) {
                convertedOutputWriter.append((char) LF);
            }
            if (fixedLength == -1 && character == NEL) {
                convertedChar = LF;
            } else {
                convertedChar = replaceNonPrintableCharacterByWhitespace(character);
            }

            convertedOutputWriter.append((char) character);


        }
```

Comment: А зачем файл бить на строки. Тупо блоками, кратными 4 Кб читать и обрабатывать блок, писать на диск. после чего переходим к следующему блоку. так же можно использовать какую нибудь java альтернативу функции mmap (google говорит, что это MappedByteBuffer)

Comment: читал блокам, менял разные блоки и т.п. считывал разными способами. занимает считывание и конвертация 18 часов ))

Comment: Даже не представляю что надо делать что бы 250Мб обрабатывались 18 часов. Для начала посмотрите сколько займет времени чтение и запись выбранным способом без конвертации. Объем то копеечный, за пару секунд должен читаться/писаться

Comment: Если я все правильно понимаю, то символы конвертируются один в один, то есть, можно использовать таблицу на 256 значений для перекодировки. Вполне возможно, что есть символы, которые так просто не перекодируются и нужно будет договориться о их замене. Поэтому весь цикл будет - считать блок, пробежаться циклом, записать блок. Учитывая, что скорость записи/чтения файлов больше, чем замена в памяти, работа всего алгорима ну максмимум в полтора раза будет дольше, чем просто скопировать файл. Поэтому, максимум минуту-две на 250МБайт.

Comment: @KoVadim я тоже так думал, BUFFER_SIZE = 2048, в массиве перечислял символы, которые нужно заменить на пробелы, конвертировал каждый байт и предварительно проверял нужно ли такой символ заменять. 
30 секунд занимает считывание. а конвертация 18ч. такие дела. 
1600 символов в каждой строке и по 220 000 строк. я тоже был оочень удивлен, что все так много занимает времени.

Comment: Показывайте свой алгоритм перекодирования. Там должно быть строк 5 кода - один цикл.

Comment: @KoVadim обновил вопрос

Comment: Вы читаете по байту и заполняете массив и в добавок вручную копируете массив?

Comment: если надо получить строки, то вроде можно использовать встроенные средства и кодировку [CP1047](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_1047). Или возможно какую-то другую [тысячи их...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#EBCDIC-based_code_pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как я реализовал потом
p.s. пару дней подождем другие ответы. данный способ ускорил всю процедуру до 18 минут

```
         StringTokenizer tok = null;
            try {
                tok = new StringTokenizer(ebcdicToAscii(IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(fileName))), "\r\n"); // сразу передаю в StringTokenizer, чтобы не хранить в памяти объект. 
            } catch (IOException e) {
                error("Cannot read file " + fileName);
            }
            while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String line = tok.nextToken();
                // делаешь свои дела
            }





public static String ebcdicToAscii(byte[] e) {
        try {
            return new String(ebcdicToAsciiBytes(e, 0, e.length), "ISO8859_1");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException var2) {
            return var2.toString();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] ebcdicToAsciiBytes(byte[] e, int offset, int len) {
        byte[] a = new byte[len];

        for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            a[i] = EBCDIC2ASCII[e[offset + i] & 255];
        }

        return a;
    }

    public static final byte[] EBCDIC2ASCII = new byte[] {
        (byte)0x0,  (byte)0x1,  (byte)0x2,  (byte)0x3, 
        (byte)0x9C, (byte)0x9,  (byte)0x86, (byte)0x7F, 
        (byte)0x97, (byte)0x8D, (byte)0x8E, (byte)0xB, 
        (byte)0xC,  (byte)0xD,  (byte)0xE,  (byte)0xF, 
        (byte)0x10, (byte)0x11, (byte)0x12, (byte)0x13, 
        (byte)0x9D, (byte)0xA,  (byte)0x8,  (byte)0x87, 
        (byte)0x18, (byte)0x19, (byte)0x92, (byte)0x8F, 
        (byte)0x1C, (byte)0x1D, (byte)0x1E, (byte)0x1F, 
        (byte)0x80, (byte)0x81, (byte)0x82, (byte)0x83, 
        (byte)0x84, (byte)0x85, (byte)0x17, (byte)0x1B, 
        (byte)0x88, (byte)0x89, (byte)0x8A, (byte)0x8B, 
        (byte)0x8C, (byte)0x5,  (byte)0x6,  (byte)0x7, 
        (byte)0x90, (byte)0x91, (byte)0x16, (byte)0x93, 
        (byte)0x94, (byte)0x95, (byte)0x96, (byte)0x4, 
        (byte)0x98, (byte)0x99, (byte)0x9A, (byte)0x9B, 
        (byte)0x14, (byte)0x15, (byte)0x9E, (byte)0x1A, 
        (byte)0x20, (byte)0xA0, (byte)0xE2, (byte)0xE4, 
        (byte)0xE0, (byte)0xE1, (byte)0xE3, (byte)0xE5, 
        (byte)0xE7, (byte)0xF1, (byte)0xA2, (byte)0x2E, 
        (byte)0x3C, (byte)0x28, (byte)0x2B, (byte)0x7C, 
        (byte)0x26, (byte)0xE9, (byte)0xEA, (byte)0xEB, 
        (byte)0xE8, (byte)0xED, (byte)0xEE, (byte)0xEF, 
        (byte)0xEC, (byte)0xDF, (byte)0x21, (byte)0x24, 
        (byte)0x2A, (byte)0x29, (byte)0x3B, (byte)0x5E, 
        (byte)0x2D, (byte)0x2F, (byte)0xC2, (byte)0xC4, 
        (byte)0xC0, (byte)0xC1, (byte)0xC3, (byte)0xC5, 
        (byte)0xC7, (byte)0xD1, (byte)0xA6, (byte)0x2C, 
        (byte)0x25, (byte)0x5F, (byte)0x3E, (byte)0x3F, 
        (byte)0xF8, (byte)0xC9, (byte)0xCA, (byte)0xCB, 
        (byte)0xC8, (byte)0xCD, (byte)0xCE, (byte)0xCF, 
        (byte)0xCC, (byte)0x60, (byte)0x3A, (byte)0x23, 
        (byte)0x40, (byte)0x27, (byte)0x3D, (byte)0x22, 
        (byte)0xD8, (byte)0x61, (byte)0x62, (byte)0x63, 
        (byte)0x64, (byte)0x65, (byte)0x66, (byte)0x67, 
        (byte)0x68, (byte)0x69, (byte)0xAB, (byte)0xBB, 
        (byte)0xF0, (byte)0xFD, (byte)0xFE, (byte)0xB1, 
        (byte)0xB0, (byte)0x6A, (byte)0x6B, (byte)0x6C, 
        (byte)0x6D, (byte)0x6E, (byte)0x6F, (byte)0x70, 
        (byte)0x71, (byte)0x72, (byte)0xAA, (byte)0xBA, 
        (byte)0xE6, (byte)0xB8, (byte)0xC6, (byte)0xA4, 
        (byte)0xB5, (byte)0x7E, (byte)0x73, (byte)0x74, 
        (byte)0x75, (byte)0x76, (byte)0x77, (byte)0x78, 
        (byte)0x79, (byte)0x7A, (byte)0xA1, (byte)0xBF, 
        (byte)0xD0, (byte)0x5B, (byte)0xDE, (byte)0xAE, 
        (byte)0xAC, (byte)0xA3, (byte)0xA5, (byte)0xB7, 
        (byte)0xA9, (byte)0xA7, (byte)0xB6, (byte)0xBC, 
        (byte)0xBD, (byte)0xBE, (byte)0xDD, (byte)0xA8, 
        (byte)0xAF, (byte)0x5D, (byte)0xB4, (byte)0xD7, 
        (byte)0x7B, (byte)0x41, (byte)0x42, (byte)0x43, 
        (byte)0x44, (byte)0x45, (byte)0x46, (byte)0x47, 
        (byte)0x48, (byte)0x49, (byte)0xAD, (byte)0xF4, 
        (byte)0xF6, (byte)0xF2, (byte)0xF3, (byte)0xF5, 
        (byte)0x7D, (byte)0x4A, (byte)0x4B, (byte)0x4C, 
        (byte)0x4D, (byte)0x4E, (byte)0x4F, (byte)0x50, 
        (byte)0x51, (byte)0x52, (byte)0xB9, (byte)0xFB, 
        (byte)0xFC, (byte)0xF9, (byte)0xFA, (byte)0xFF, 
        (byte)0x5C, (byte)0xF7, (byte)0x53, (byte)0x54, 
        (byte)0x55, (byte)0x56, (byte)0x57, (byte)0x58, 
        (byte)0x59, (byte)0x5A, (byte)0xB2, (byte)0xD4, 
        (byte)0xD6, (byte)0xD2, (byte)0xD3, (byte)0xD5, 
        (byte)0x30, (byte)0x31, (byte)0x32, (byte)0x33, 
        (byte)0x34, (byte)0x35, (byte)0x36, (byte)0x37, 
        (byte)0x38, (byte)0x39, (byte)0xB3, (byte)0xDB, 
        (byte)0xDC, (byte)0xD9, (byte)0xDA, (byte)0x9F
    };
```